# Unable to run java application (exe) converted using launch4j

Tags: java, jar, launch4j

I converted a java program (Number Guessing Game) to .jar but it did not run on double clicking so,ran it on cmd (it worked) now i converted it to .exe using launch4j but the application does not work either . Help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your jar file with one zip application (ex winrar)
2. go to META-INF folder and open the file MAINIFEST.MF
3. put your main class there as follows

> Main-Class: your-packaging.YourMainClass

4. save this file and try to create your exe file again

*This will make your jar **runnable**, therefore when you create an exe file using Launch4J, your application will execute once you double click on that*

> If in any case your application did not run again, you have
>   **dependency problem**. for solving that you should also add **Class-Path:**  within your **MANIFEST.MF** file!

Comment: Hey @mehdi. Thanks for responding. I opened the MANIFEST.MF file and saw something like this **Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: practice
Created-By: 11.0.1 (Oracle Corporation)** what am i supposed to do now ? Please note that the name of my main class is practice and what's  packaging ?

Comment: @RohitGarg packaging is practically the folders you put your classes in them, if you create some folders and put your "practice" class there. you must put it here this way: my-folder-name1.my-folder-name2.ETC.practice until your app to work!